# Base64 Image Encoding - Why it makes call to server if the encoded image is in the src string

Tags: html, base64

I am using Base64 Encoded image which is being referred in the html as

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,asdfggggxxx ..."></img>
```

The image appears fine but I always see an error in the browser saying "414 Request-URI Too Large"

Why does it make a call to the server if the encoded image data is in the src itself.

Is there a way to avoid this error ?

Comment: In any case, there is an error in the image tag. You never put </img> at the end. Either we code: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,asdfggggxxx ..."> or <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,asdfggggxxx ..." />. But I don't think it will solve your problem...

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeColette In XHTML, yes, but [not in HTML5](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/to-close-or-not-to-close-tags-in-html5).

Comment: I was able to fix it by removing double quotes ("") wrapping data image. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by removing double quotes ("") wrapping data image. Thank you.